# Laravel Ajax search gives the whole collection as response to the query after input is cleared from input box

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel

The response should show no results as I clear the input fields for the search feature but instead it is giving the full collection. It works fine when there is input but once I clear it the whole collection is showing. Here is the Laravel Controller Class.

```
 public function search(Request $request)
    {  if($request->ajax()){

        $results = DB::table('PROPERTY_TAGS')->where('TAG_NAME','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")->get();
        $output='';
        if(count($results)>0){
            foreach($results as $result){
                $output.='<p>'.$result->TAG_NAME.'</p>';
            }

        }else{
            $output="<p>no data found</p>'";

        }
         return $output;
     }
}
```

Here is my HTML with laravel blade template :

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col s9 "> <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" /></div>
      <div class="col s3"><a href="sass.html"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a></div>
      <div class="col s12">
            <b>Ex: </b><i>Beltola, Zoo Road</i>

            <!-- Suggestions will be displayed in below div. -->
            <div id="display"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is the script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
});

$('#search').on('keyup',function(){
    $value=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : '/search',
        data:{'search':$value},
        success:function(data){
            if(data == '\0'){
                $('#display').text('');
            }
               $('#display').html(data).show();
               //alert(data.success);
                }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Skip the Ajax call if there is an empty string? `If ($value.length === 0) return;`?

Comment: Naah mate now the ajax function totally halts. Didn't worked

Comment: "Halts" doesn't mean much to me. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to make the Xhr request if the string is empty. Could add a little check for that as shown below.

```
$('#search').on('keyup',function() {
  var value = $(this).val();

  //ADD THIS... ++
  if (value.length === 0) {
    //clear results
    $('#display').text('');
    //no query, just return.
    return;
  }
  //++

  $.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : '/search',
    data:{'search': value},
    success:function(data) {
      if (data == '\0') {
        $('#display').text('');
      }
      $('#display').html(data).show();
      //alert(data.success);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Cancelling the event for ajax works. However, I wonder why the like operator is giving the whole collection for a null value

Comment: Glad that worked! Not a null value I think but an empty string, so this is a wildcard search returning everything: `'LIKE','%'.$request->search."%"`. You could handle it PHP controller side too but makes more sense to not make the Xhr request in the first place. Might even want to wait till say 3 letters entered before searching, depending what you are searching on.